# How to make Apple TV play episodes consecutively?

Tags: appletv, television

I have a 3rd-gen Apple TV. I recently started ripping and adding some of my TV Shows from DVD and I've stumbled into a problem.

Some of TV shows episodes are played consecutively (one-by-one without my intervention) while some are not and after the playback the screen goes back to episode selection menu. This happens on iTunes 11.0.5 on Windows and the versions available since mid-2012. Similarly Apple TV is updated anytime a software update is released for that device as I always use the latest stable software available. I play the movies/TV shows on my Apple TV via HomeSharing.

My guess is that I must have tagged some of them badly and they're not recognized as consecutive or of the same titles maybe.

Can someone suggest what I might have done wrong?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? Is it still something that you can reproduce - if so, let's edit in the version of iTunes you are using and how exactly the Apple TV is playing the files (home sharing or some other manner)

Comment: @bmike Question updated.

Comment: Thank you - let's see if someone has a solution - this might be worth me putting some bounty down too if no-one jumps in with some more detail.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a Playlist or Smart Playlist and choose the episode from that it will continue to the next item auotmatically.

Comment: I know it can be achieved without Playlists, so that's a workaround. I'm looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found that if I just go into the library using the AppleTV regularly, it will always return me to the Episode selection screen, however if I use the Remote app on my iPhone or iPad to first select the AppleTV, and then point it at my iTunes library, and then select the episode (all on the Remote app, without changing any screens on my AppleTV till I select an episode), then the episodes will play one after the other. This is a very consistent thing for me at least :)

Answer (score 0):

Select the track in iTunes and Get Info. On the 3rd tab ("Video") ensure that the Season Number and Episode Number are correctly filled out. Also double check that the Sorting tab is blank (this is only necessary if you are custom sorting tracks).

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you certain that when ripping from DVD every episode has been made into its own file? Perhaps the episodes that are playing consecutively are actually a single file with chapter markers? — I'm not aware of a setting on the Apple TV to play tv shows automatically without using a playlist.

Comment: Definitely separate files. I was surprised myself that they play consecutively, but they did.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going into the episode details page and clicking "play" from there, you can hit the "play" button on the remote from the season episode list to directly play the file. Sorry if this was obvious- I just discovered this after using the Apple TV for six months.
It saves you a few seconds, and the clicks to enter and back out of the specific episode page. If only they would add the continuous play feature for tv shows now...